# Minicom and kermit,where is my fault?

Tags: system-v, kermit

I want to transfer a big file of 70MB to a virtual machine
running an ancient unix(at&t 2.1 ),no cdrom driver,no ufs
disk(linux give me error when i try to mount systemV ufs,with
ufs 43bsd ok),no floppy(no 70MB floppy exist..)
So i choose minicom+kermit
On at&t side i give

```
kermit -g file.tar
```

On linux side i open minicom

```
ctrl+a+s
```

choose kermit,choose file.tar and wow...nothing happen.
On at&t serial screen i see

```
/usr/local/bin/kermit -g file.tar                                                           
Return to your local Kermit and give a SERVER command.                                                                  

KERMIT READY TO GET...                                                                                                  
3 EToo many retries_N"U1@
```

Any solution?

Comment: As it just happens... I was working on this last weekend :-). https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CVP4hp1W4AAbzGY.png. Will get back to you on this...

Comment: I'd suggest `kermit -O` on the AT&T side, and then `kermit` on the local side (`set line /dev/tty...`, `set baud 19200`, `set carrier-watch off`, `set flow-control none`, `send file.tar`)

Comment: Can you check, in minicom, that both hw and sw flow control are off?

Comment: Does the VM have a network interface?  does it have NFS client software?  if so, you could create an NFS export somewhere (on the VM's host machine, perhaps) and mount it on the VM.  Even without NFS, it might have an ftp client or possibly even a http client you could use to download the file over the network.

Comment: AT&T unix no tcp drivers avaliable anywhere

Comment: " that both hw and sw flow control are off?" yes both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have success, First I think the kermit program was "embedded" in Minicom because it give no error about path (except if you give the comamnd "run kermit").

Fast guide:

CLIENT: Slackware 15
SERVER: Unix System V SVR4 without networking, because qemu don't support the WD8003 board, on libvirt

on CLIENT install ckermit

```
sudo sbopkg -B -i ckermit
```

on SERVER activate the getty

```
vi /etc/inittab

1r:12345:respawn:/etc/getty tty00 19200
```

the do init q

```
init q
```

On CLIENT we need which serial is using the old good SVR4

```
virsh ttyconsole Unixvm
/dev/pts/7
```

On CLIENT we connect with minicom

```
minicom -D /dev/pts/7
```

after login to Unix SERVER
we configure minicom path on minicom (ctrl+o, configure path, etc..)

On SERVER we have the kermit program (search for binary for Unix on the net)

```
./KERMIT
C-Kermit, 4F(077) 1 Apr 89, AT&T System III/System V
Type ? for help
C-Kermit>server

C-Kermit server starting.  Return to your local machine by typing
its escape sequence for closing the connection, and issue further
commands from there.  To shut down the C-Kermit server, issue the
FINISH or BYE command and then reconnect.
```

on client minicom press ctrl+a then s, select minicom, select path of file to transfer

[image]

slow..but work!

Remind that on SVR4 the default file limit is 2048 kbytes, so transfer of files over 2mb will fail, the solution is to use ulimit (works on ksh, not on bash) before start kermit

```
ulimit -f yourvalue
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used [qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) + [QEmu Monitor](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Monitor) to mount floppies and read the raw data with dd.

## Write your file one floppy at a time with `dd` or `split`:

Note: You may need to split into volumes of 1474560 (that's what /dev/rdsk/f03ht seems to be).

You can optionally try to use `compress` as well.

```
# Archive the files you wish to send using `tar` (supported on SYSV). 
$ ls -la test.tar
----------+ 1 cmihai None 5901312 Dec  2 20:55 test.tar

# Split into 1.44MB volumes
$ split -b 1478656 test.tar test_floppy_

$ ls -la test_floppy*
-rw-r--r--+ 1 cmihai None 1478656 Dec  2 21:10 test_floppy_aa
-rw-r--r--+ 1 cmihai None 1478656 Dec  2 21:10 test_floppy_ab
-rw-r--r--+ 1 cmihai None 1478656 Dec  2 21:10 test_floppy_ac
-rw-r--r--+ 1 cmihai None 1465344 Dec  2 21:10 test_floppy_ad
```

## Mount the floppy in `qemu`.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> in `qemu` to use the qemu monitor.

```
change floppy0 test_floppy_aa
info block
```

## Go back your terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>

Note: We should probably read off the raw device /dev/rdsk/f03ht not the block device... to test.

```
dd if=/dev/dsk/f03ht of=test_floppy_aa
dd if=/dev/dsk/f03ht of=test_floppy_ab
...
```

## Unpack

```
cat a b c | tar -tvt test_floppy_* # test..
cat a b c | tar -xvt test_floppy_*
```

## Other ideas

- `qemu-system-i386 -hda sysv.img -hdb test.tar` and read with `dd` from `/dev/rdsk/1s1` (I guess... 0s0 is the root disk). You can also try to `fdisk /dev/rdsk/1s1'.
- Append to the end of the existing disk image, and read with `dd` :D. (insane...)
- May need to use /dev/fd or /dev/rdsk devices...
- Converting from `RAW` to `VMDK` (usable by VMware and VirtualBox): `qemu-img  convert -O vmdk sysv.img sysv.vmdk`. Now we can try to see if VMware or VirtualBox NIC drivers are supported...
- Will try `kermit` / `tip` / `cu` as soon as I find the *floppy* that contains them and the `/dev/` I need to use...

## Notes:

- tar can read directly from /dev/dsk/f03ht. Ex: `tar -tvf /dev/dsk/f03ht`. Should probably try to create a multi volume floppy and forget about the dd part... WIP :-).

Comment: 70MB of data via floppy? Seriously?

Comment: Going to be faster than kermit / minicom... that's for sure :-). Besides, this thing gets installed from 43 floppies (or so..). Not much else you can do if you don't have a filesystem driver, a cdrom device or a network stack...

Comment: Advantage of `kermit`/`minicom` is that you can walk away from it, though. Two minutes per floppy... assume two (or three) floppies on the go... around a couple of hours of swapping. Yes, ok, I suppose it's not too bad.

Comment: Cu is a good idea. OP will only need cu on one side, and it's easy to install from linux distro repositories. Would need uuencode on the Linux side and uudecode on the SVR2 side.